# What is the difference between getTemporaryDirectory() and getApplicationSupportDirectory()?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

What is the main difference between `await getTemporaryDirectory();`
and `await getApplicationSupportDirectory()` with Flutter Path provider package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is mentioned that what is the underlying calls made for the function:

[getTemporaryDirectory](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getTemporaryDirectory.html) , [getApplicationSupportDirectory](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationSupportDirectory.html)

Considering the example of Android, the path returned by both methods should be used for storing the app-related data.

But there is a minor difference that for the files inside the path returned by `getTemporaryDirectory` ,  the system will automatically delete files in this directory as disk space is needed elsewhere on the device. The system will always delete older files first, based on the lastModifiedTime.

Storage permission won't be required for both the methods.

Answer (score 4):

As per documentation :

[getTemporaryDirectory](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getTemporaryDirectory.html) :

> Path to the temporary directory on the device that is not backed up and is suitable for storing caches of downloaded files.
>
> Files in this directory may be cleared at any time. This does not
> return a new temporary directory. Instead, the caller is responsible
> for creating (and cleaning up) files or directories within this
> directory. This directory is scoped to the calling application.
>
> On iOS, this uses the NSCachesDirectory API.
>
> On Android, this uses the getCacheDir API on the context.

[getApplicationSupportDirectory](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationSupportDirectory.html) :

> Path to a directory where the application may place application
> support files.
>
> Use this for files you don’t want exposed to the user. Your app should
> not use this directory for user data files.
>
> On iOS, this uses the NSApplicationSupportDirectory API. If this
> directory does not exist, it is created automatically.
>
> On Android, this function uses the getFilesDir API on the context.